# how to create an object of different java class in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I have created a servlet and on that I have a hyperlink on it. On clicking that link I need to call a constructor of a different java class. As we cannot create the object directly, I have created a function in a script tag and trying to create the object in that function.

My question is: is it possible to create an object of a different class in a function in script tag and if yes, then how to do it?

Comment: reading the question, it seems like you want to create a Java object in Javascript

Comment: Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: @Arg0n He's using j2ee

Comment: Please make your question more understandable. I think I've understood it, but a good asked question has to give me the certitude I understood it.

Comment: The Java objects are created on the *server* side. Javascript works on the *client* side (the browser). I think you have some confusion there, but perhaps you should clarify the question by adding the server and client code that you are talking about (only the relevant parts).